# When A ClassVisitor's visitMethod will be called in asm?

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm, bytecode-manipulation

Let's say I have class like this:

```
public class ClassPrinter extends ClassVisitor {


    public ClassPrinter(ClassWriter writer) {
        super(Opcodes.ASM5, writer);
    }

    @Override
    public void visit(int version, int access, String name, String signature, String superName, String[] interfaces) {
        super.visit(version, access, name, signature, superName, interfaces);
    }

    @Override
    public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, String desc, String signature, String[] exceptions) {
        // when this line will get executed?
        System.out.println(name);
    }

}
```

now when the `visitMethod` will be called? Is it when the classloading happens in Java (thats where class visitor gets called?) or when a method is called on the class object?

I'm getting confused on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`visitMethod` gets called when you directly or indirectly call the visitor. This is completely unrelated to class loading or execution in the JVM.

ASM uses the visitor pattern. You pass in a class implementing the callbacks you are interested in, and then you pass it to something like `ClassNode.accept(cv)` and the ClassNode will automatically call all your callbacks for the appropriate parts of the classfile.

Comment: Thanks Animony. I still have few questions, let's say I use the above code to build a java agent and load at my application start time. Then during my application run, will all method names get printed  via visitMethod? For example let's say in my application there is a method call `a.test()` then will I get test method and its corresponding method calls traced?

Comment: @Ant's: **No**, this visitor is for processing a *class*, not for tracing an *execution*. When you really want to enter such a topic like byte code manipulation, you should stop basing your programming on guesswork. Start reading the documentation where the purpose of the library is explained, before ever looking at the API…

Answer (score 0):

Normally you chain a `ClassVisitor` like that to a `ClassReader`, which reads a given class and triggers all `visit*` methods

```
ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(className);
cr.accept(new ClassPrinter(), 0);
```

When you want to read the class (and print the method name) is totally up to you.

If however you want to *transform* a class and load it to the JVM, a possibility is to subclass [`ClassLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html), where you read the class, transform it (by using `visit*` methods), and write it with `ClassWriter`. See the ASM's `examples` folder (e.g. `Annotations.java`) from some code examples.